# spring outer transaction propagation new and inner required

Tags: spring, transactions

Just wanted to understand the behavior of transactions in case if the propagation of outer transaction is marked as New and propagation of inner transaction is marked as Required. If the inner transaction fails will the transaction roll back as a whole or only the inner transaction.

Comment: Can some one provide input on this. I have seen articles on spring transactions where they have explained about what would happen if the outer transaction is marked as required and inner transaction as new but not the other way round.

Comment: Can some provide information on this.

Answer (score 0):

If the inner transaction is marked as `Required` it will just join the outer one previously created, so there will be only one transaction.